# How to paginate a custom query it in cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

```
$l = $this->Manager->query("SELECT leave_application.id
         from leave_application INNER JOIN emp_managers ON (leave_application.employee_id = emp_managers.employee_id) 
         WHERE emp_managers.manager_id =" . $this->Session->read('Auth.Manager.id')
         ." AND leave_application.approve_1 !=". $id ." AND leave_application.approve_2 != ". $id 
         ." AND leave_application.approve_3 != ". $id);
```

**EDIT**
this is what I tried but it did'nt work:

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query("SELECT leave_application.id as leaveID, leave_application.approve_1,leave_application.employee_id,
        leave_application.approve_2, leave_application.days_desired ,leave_application.approve_3,leave_application.leave_from, 
        leave_application.leave_to, employees.id, employees.firstname , employees.lastname, emp_managers.employee_id as empmanagers_id 
        from leave_application INNER JOIN emp_managers ON (leave_application.employee_id = emp_managers.employee_id) 
        INNER JOIN employees on (employees.id = emp_managers.employee_id)
        WHERE emp_managers.manager_id =" . CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id')
    ." and leave_application.approve_1 !=". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id')
    ." and leave_application.approve_2 != ". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id')
    ." and leave_application.approve_3 != ". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id'));
}

function paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count  
        from leave_application INNER JOIN emp_managers ON (leave_application.employee_id = emp_managers.employee_id) 
        INNER JOIN employees on (employees.id = emp_managers.employee_id)
        WHERE emp_managers.manager_id =" . CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id')
    ." and leave_application.approve_1 !=". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id')
    ." and leave_application.approve_2 != ". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id') 
    ." and leave_application.approve_3 != ". CakeSession::read('Auth.Manager.id'));
}
```

Comment: check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778333/cakephp-afterfind-and-pagination-order-not-working

Answer (score 0):

add these methods to your model of controller with same query without limit keyword

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query('SELECT ...');
}

function paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra)
{
    return $this->query('SELECT COUNT(.....');
}
```

Comment: Use pagination as you generally used in cake php. if you want to make pagination work with custom query than add these 2 methods in your model (Manager). So that default pagination method would be override for this particular model.

Comment: The query is actually working on models other than the manager model

Comment: I have done what you said but i get the following error

Comment: Fatal Error
Error: Unsupported operand types 
File: C:\wamp\www\leave.com\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent.php
Line: 214

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp